# Excel Formula Help Request - Delimeter and Counter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, delimiter

How can separate the data given the data below by warehouse, and count each item by the quantity provided next to the item?

```
WAREHOUSE1-ITEM1-2-ITEM2-1-ITEM3-1-ITEM4-2-ITEM5-1
WAREHOUSE2-ITEM1-1-ITEM2-2-ITEM3-3-ITEM4-4-ITEM5-5
```

Comment: What output do you expect from given sample?

Comment: Separate into columns and use countifs()

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Select the column with the data
2. DATA -> Text to Columns -> Delimited
3. Tick OTHER and place "-" in the text box
4. Finish

Then if you want to count each item simply call =SUM() below each item

Cheers